# Fundamental group of the graph of a continuous function

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous function between two topological spaces, what can we assert about the fundamental group of its graph?

I think for example to a real function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. In this case, my intuition reveals that it is trivial, but I have no clue of how formalize the argument in this particular and, above all, to explain what happens in the general case.

Comment: The graph may not be path-connected. For example, consider $X=\mathbb{Q}$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x$. Thus the fundamental group is undefined.

Comment: As the canonical projection $G_f \to X$ is a homeo, the fundamental group of the graph $G_f$ is naturally isomorphic to that of $X$.